# Changing ElementRef dynamically on Angular Overlay to reposition it?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm building a form grid in Angular and I was trying to implement popovers/tooltips for invalid input fields. I ended up using an overlay for it after trying Material and NG-Bootstrap. But I can't seem to get it's position to be dynamic and appear over the input with the error. My position strategy has is flex connected to ElementRef which is set when the page loads. The errors all appear but only under the first input field on the form. Is there a way that I can change it's position relative to whichever input has the error? Like getting the ElementRef of the input passed to the directive somehow?

**page.component.html** - Directive show/hide functions are run on input validation

```
<input
    id="{{ 'employerName' + index }}"
    Input
    formControlName="employerCheck"
    name="valid"
    displayMessage="realtime"
    type="text"
    (status)="this.incomeForm.get('employerCheck').invalid ? tooltip.show(tests('employerName')) : tooltip.hide()"
    #tooltip="CIZTooltip"
    />
```

**page.component.ts** -
Only contains the tests function which returns a string relative to it's parameter and the inputs errorCode.

**tooltip.directive.ts**

```
    @Directive({
    selector: '[CIZTooltip],
    exportAs: 'CIZTooltip'
    })

    export class CIZTooltipDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('CIZTooltip') text = '';
    private overlayRef: OverlayRef;

    constructor(
        private overlay: Overlay,
        private overlayPositionBuilder: OverlayPositionBuilder,
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private scrollStrategyOptions: ScrollStrategyOptions,
        ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}



    show(tipText?: string, element?: ElementRef): void {        
        if (this.overlayRef) {
            this.overlayRef.detach();
        }

        const positionStrategy = this.overlayPositionBuilder.flexibleConnectedTo(this.elementRef).withPositions([
            {
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'bottom',
                overlayX: 'center',
                overlayY: 'top',
                offsetY: 8,
            },
        ]);
        const scrollStrategy = this.scrollStrategyOptions.reposition({ scrollThrottle: 10, autoClose: true });

        this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({ positionStrategy, scrollStrategy });

        if (!this.overlayRef.hasAttached()) {

            const tooltipRef: ComponentRef<CIZTooltipComponent> = this.overlayRef.attach(
                new ComponentPortal(CIZTooltipComponent)
            );
            tooltipRef.instance.text = tipText || this.text;
        }
    }

    hide(): void {
        this.overlayRef.detach();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but please... use this instead `[id]="'employerName' + index"`

Comment: @Ploppy What reason? I'm new to Angular and I'm interested in doing everything correctly.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, you can't find the code you've written in the official doc. Plus it's 2 more characters. Databinding to attributes is done with `[...]="..."`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in case anyone else runs into this issue.

First add @ViewChild to the component for each field

```
@ViewChild('employer') employerField: Element;
```

then I passed that into the show function I had setup for the tooltip in the html

```
(status)="this.incomeForm.get('employerCheck').invalid ? tooltip.show(tests('employerName'), this.employerField) : tooltip.hide()"
```

I then use that in flexibleConnectedTo in the directive function to change the position

```
show(tipText?: string, element?: any): void {       
        if (this.overlayRef) {
            this.overlayRef.detach();
        }

        const positionStrategy = this.overlayPositionBuilder.flexibleConnectedTo(element).withPositions([
            {
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'bottom',
                overlayX: 'center',
                overlayY: 'top',
                offsetY: 8,
            },
        ]);
```

No I just need to figure out loading multiple tooltips and not having them bump into each other.